# page scrolls under fancybox in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, scroll, fancybox

Page scrolls under fancybox in Google Chrome. If text under image is longer, the end of it remains invisible.

Please check tip # 16 on Fancybox page: "Disable "locked" feature - the content is locked in the overlay by default" in Chrome and compare the pop-up/page behavior to that in Firefox, for instance.

In Firefox fancybox scrolls with the page, but not in Chrome. How to make it scroll in Chrome? Is there any fix?

Answer (score 0):

I have it solved! `overlay : { locked : false }` was the key. See here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XaWZE/1175/)